# Syncing multiple folders with rsync

Tags: 19.04, rsync

In the past I used to keep two folders on my laptop synced with their respective equivalents on an external hard disk. I used [Grsync](http://www.opbyte.it/grsync/) and ran it twice whenever I wanted to sync.
Now I'm using a more complex distribution of my files and would like to sync more than two folders with their respective external equivalents.

In other words, I want to to sync (one way) say:

```
/home/user/Folder1 with /extHDD/Folder1
/home/user/Folder2 with /extHDD/Folder2
etc
```

Instead of running grsync multiple times, is there a simpler way to

1. Specify a series of source and destination directories
2. Have the possibility to check what would be changed before actually syncing.

I'm open to CLI or GUI methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html) ([more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync)) ([examples](https://www.howtogeek.com/135533/how-to-use-rsync-to-backup-your-data-on-linux/)) itself is a viable option, which

1. allows you to specify a series of source and destination directories, and
2. due to its --dry-run option which shows you what will happen without actually moving files (as [described in point 9 here)](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/).